# order the DF by changing columns values to new rows

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
Time Image Mean
0    A1    1
1    A1    2
0    B1    3
1    B1    4
```

And I want to change this as following (remove image column, add the Image values as a row header and put the values of the mean):

```
Time A1  B1
0    1   3    
1    2   4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
print(
    df.pivot(index="Time", columns="Image", values="Mean")
    .reset_index()
    .rename_axis("", axis=1)
)
```

Prints:

```
   Time  A1  B1
0     0   1   3
1     1   2   4
```